# On powershell, i have a code that sends IP details in an email but when the resulting email is received it comes out like @{IPV4Address=10.240.47.197}

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am new to powershell and coding in general. I Have been asked to write a code with specific details that sends an email out to someone. I am 90% complete. One of the details is asking for an IP address and I have managed to find the IP but when the email is sent it comes out like @{IPV4Address=10.240.47.197}. Any suggestions on how to getting just the IP and not the ip4 blah.

The current code i have that collects the IP is

```
$ipaddress = Test-Connection $serverName -count 1 | select Ipv4Address 
$servString += FormatCell -cellValue $ipaddress
```

Would Really appreciate the help

thanks

Osman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `IPV4Address` property, so `$ipaddress.IPV4Address`, or something. Something like:

```
$ipaddress = Test-Connection $serverName -count 1
$servString += FormatCell -cellValue $ipaddress.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick reply, when i trying and do that. the table i have sent in the email just has the full IP details and thats it. Would it be easier if i showed the full code

Comment: Excellent thats done it. Thank you for your help really appreciate it :)